# Trip to the Everglades National Park

Tags: usa, safety, national-parks

I am going with my wife on a one week cruise in January from Ft Lauderdale. I arrive in the US and Ft Lauderdale a few days before the cruise for a quick visit to Key West. I was first thinking that we might stop on the way down for a one day visit to the National Park.

I am now worried that all our luggage for the cruise won´t fit in the trunk the therefore some part of it might be visible in the rental car during the whole day at some parking lot outside the National Park. I have therefore started to look at the possibility of a day-tour from and back to Ft Lauderdale instead.

**Edit: The trip is from Ft L to Key West - there is no option of leaving luggage on the airport. If my car trunk turns out to be too small, some of it it will be visible in the back seat unless there is some storage at the national park or leaving luggage visible is still OK. I have to assume the trunk may be too small. The alternative is to awkwardly order out a flight of cars and check them for trunk size at the cal rental**

Am I being overly cautious here or is my second approach the natural way to arrange the trip?

Comment: What is your exact question? Whether your luggage fits in the trunk will depend on your luggage and on the size of the trunk. Neither of which we can really answer for you. You could also probably leave your luggage at the airport I don't know about FLL, but most airports have luggage storage for a reasonable fee.

Comment: A much more useful question would be where to leave the luggage in Key West or Fort Lauderdale rather then ask for an opinion of the options chosen by you.

Comment: That's a good option. I didn't think of that. I´m coming back to a different Ft Lauderdale hotel but I might still check that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on your appetite for risk. The parking lot at Everglades does have a security patrol and is fairly busy, but they aren't responsible for any losses incurred. I personally wouldn't care if someone can see my luggage in the backseat, but that's me.